# How to update UI after 2 seconds after showing Loading and using setTimeout in createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to display the dishes which is rendered on home component after showing loading for 2 sec
but unable to do this. I have doubts in createAsyncThunk part mostly.

```
// This is the structure of DISHES which i am importing
// DISHES = [
    {id: 0, name: "Uthappizza", image: "/assets/images/uthappizza.png", category: "mains",label: "Hot",},
    {id: 1,name: "Zucchipakoda",image: "/assets/image/zucchipakoda.png",
category: "appetizer",}]

const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    errMsg: null,
    dishes: [],
};
export const getDishes = createAsyncThunk("dishes/getDishes", () => {
    //return setTimeout(() => {
        //return DISHES;
    //}, 2000);
// I have tried to convert it like this
return DISHES;

//And from useEffect I am using setTimeout
});
export const dishesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "dishes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getDishes.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        [getDishes.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action);
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.dishes = state.dishes.concat(action.payload);
        },
        [getDishes.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
        },
    },
});

export default dishesSlice.reducer;
```

after above file I am trying this in home component but it is not working
I am not getting correct values in payload on dishes/fullfilled action
In redux devtools action is dispatching successfull and showing loading but after that there is error

```
import { getDishes } from "../redux/stateSlices/dishesSlice";

const { dishes, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.dishes);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
// upadated code and using setTimeout here
       setTimeout(()=>{
         dispatch(getDishes());
      },2000)
    }, []);

if(isLoading){
return <Loading/>
}else {
return (...)
}
```

Now it is rendering ui as expected. First displaying the loading... for 2 seconds then showing home page but Now the problem here is that
redux actions are getting called continuously and it is overloading the memory. Like one it is loading it should show pending and once it is loaded is should show fullfilled but the pending and fullfilled cycle goes on continuously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function won't return promise. Please update like this.

```
() => {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
           resolve(DISHES);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: It is not working. In redux devtools actions are getting dispatched continuoulsy. and Ui is stuck at loading only

Comment: Please check this code. https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-test-jje745

Comment: It is working fine if I return any string or something and it is getting fullfilled. But as soon as pass DISHES which is array of object it is getting in continuous loop of pending and fullfilled. Don't know why. Rest it is working fine as you have suggested.

Comment: I was doing mistake by dispatching same action on Main component which is parent component and Home component which is child component of Main and it was conflicting and creating error. So I updated the code and dispatched the action in Main component only. And it is working as expected. But thanks man. You helped me to implement the functionality and making me realise  that I should return promise in createAsyncThunk. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome, great.